# How to add namespace in Unit Test Library(Windows store apps)?

Tags: unit-testing, using, windows-store-apps

I have some test class

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.UnitTestFramework;
using Praktyka.Models;

namespace PraktykaTest
{
    [TestClass]
    public class PictureManagerTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void LoadImagesTest()
        {
           var pic = new PictureManager();
            pic.LoadImages(new List<String>
                                               {
                                                   "1.jpg",
                                                   "2.jpg"
                                               });

          // Assert.AreEqual(@"dataImages\1.jpg",pic.Current().UriSource);
           Assert.AreEqual("test","test");
        }
    }
}
```

I have compile error

```
The type or namespace name 'List' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
Cannot initialize object of type 'List<string>' with a collection initializer
```

How to add reference for correct working with Lists ?

Comment: I add 'using System.Collections.Generic;' but i have some trouble with code highlight. [image](http://imageshack.us/a/img62/9717/intellisense.png)

Comment: After restaring Visual Studio highlight work correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add a reference to the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace to get the generic List<> class. Then try recompiling.

Comment: If you are in Visual studio, as long as the assembly is referenced and this one should be, but you don't know which name space. Right click on top of List<String> and select Resolve and it will pop it in for you, or fully qualify it if that's what you want.